# How would I fill a ListBox from backgroundworker?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, listbox, backgroundworker

I am having troubles filling a listbox from a backgroundworker thread. I currently have the following code:

```
    private void backgroundWorker1_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
    {
        var lockedUsers = new List<UserPrincipal>();
        using (var context = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain, "domain", smtu, smtp))
        {
            GroupPrincipal grp = GroupPrincipal.FindByIdentity(context, IdentityType.SamAccountName, "Domain Users");
            foreach (var userPrincipal in grp.GetMembers(false))
            {

                var user = UserPrincipal.FindByIdentity(context, IdentityType.SamAccountName, userPrincipal.SamAccountName);
                if (user != null)
                {
                    if (user.IsAccountLockedOut())
                    {
                        listBox1.Items.Add(@"domain\ " + user);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

This returns the exception saying I cannot write to the main UI, which is correct. But I have been unable to find a way around it. I've tried the following, and although it didn't give any errors, it didn't fill the listbox.

```
    List<string> listusers = new List<string>();


    private void backgroundWorker1_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
    {
        var lockedUsers = new List<UserPrincipal>();
        using (var context = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain, "domain", smtu, smtp))
        {
            GroupPrincipal grp = GroupPrincipal.FindByIdentity(context, IdentityType.SamAccountName, "Domain Users");
            foreach (var userPrincipal in grp.GetMembers(false))
            {

                var user = UserPrincipal.FindByIdentity(context, IdentityType.SamAccountName, userPrincipal.SamAccountName);
                if (user != null)
                {
                    if (user.IsAccountLockedOut())
                    {
                        listusers.Add(@"domain\" + user);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    private async void timerlocked_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        backgroundWorker1.RunWorkerAsync();
        listBox1.DataSource = listusers;
    }
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Instead of the timer's Tick event, use the BackgroundWorker's Completed event to set the DataSource property with that listusers collection.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I update the GUI from another thread?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/661561/how-do-i-update-the-gui-from-another-thread)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `DoWorkEventArgs` that gets passed to the `DoWorkEventHandler` delegate has a [`Result` property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.componentmodel.doworkeventargs.result)

> Gets or sets a value that represents the result of an asynchronous operation.

The `Result` that you set will be sent along to the `RunWorkerCompleted` event through the `RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs` that get passed to that delegate.

So, to solve this, you could build a `List<string>` inside of the `DoWork` event, set the `Result` property to that list, handle the `RunWorkerCompleted` event and access the list from the `RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs.Result`.

```
private void backgroundWorker1_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
{
    var result = new List<string>();
    var lockedUsers = new List<UserPrincipal>();
    using (var context = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain, "domain", smtu, smtp))
    {
        GroupPrincipal grp = GroupPrincipal.FindByIdentity(context, IdentityType.SamAccountName, "Domain Users");
        foreach (var userPrincipal in grp.GetMembers(false))
        {

            var user = UserPrincipal.FindByIdentity(context, IdentityType.SamAccountName, userPrincipal.SamAccountName);
            if (user != null)
            {
                if (user.IsAccountLockedOut())
                {
                    result.Add(@"domain\ " + user);
                }
            }
        }
    }
    e.Result = result;
}

private void backgroundWorker1_RunWorkerCompleted(object sender, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Error != null)
    {
        // Error handling.
    }
    if (e.Cancelled)
    {
       // If you support cancellation...
    }
    listBox1.Items.Clear();
    listBox1.Items.AddRange((e.Result as List<string>).ToArray());
}
```

Comment: Thank you for explaining, it's working and I understand it now!

Answer (score 0):

To access the UI thread from a background worker, you can either do your work in the [`RunWorkerCompleted`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker.runworkercompleted?view=netframework-4.8)  event of the `BackgroundWorker` or - if you want to access the UI while the worker is running, have a look at [`Control.Invoke`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.control.invoke?view=netframework-4.8).

The later could look like this:

```
if (user.IsAccountLockedOut())
{
    listBox1.Invoke(() => listBox1.Items.Add(@"domain\ " + user));
}
```